# Async task crashes during doInBackground()

Tags: java, android

I'm making a file manager app for android and am trying to implement a copy and paste feature using AsyncTask to copy the files. When I attempt to paste the items, the app crashes and reports:

```
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 8494
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured     while executing doInBackground()
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at    android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at  com.example.myapp.MoveFiles.doInBackground(MoveFiles.java:30)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at com.example.myapp.MoveFiles.doInBackground(MoveFiles.java:1)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-22 16:27:48.065: E/AndroidRuntime(8494):     ... 4 more
```

Here is my AsyncTask class:

```
public class MoveFiles extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<File>, Integer, Boolean> {

private ProgressDialog pd;
private String path;

public MoveFiles(ProgressDialog pd, String path) { 
    this.pd = pd;
    this.path = path;
}

    @Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(ArrayList<File>... params) {
    ArrayList<File> files = params[0];
    int count = files.size();
    try { 
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            File destination = new File (path + "/" + files.get(i).getName());
            copyDirectory(files.get(i), destination);
            }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    pd.setMessage("Please wait..");
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pd.setMax(100);
    pd.setIndeterminate(false);
    pd.setCancelable(true);
    pd.show();
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    pd.dismiss();
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress){
}


static void copyDirectory(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation) throws IOException {
    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory() && sourceLocation.exists()) {
        if (!targetLocation.exists()) {
            targetLocation.mkdir();
        }

        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            copyDirectory(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]), new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
        }
    } else {

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

        // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    }
    if (DisplayDirectoryActivity.getCut()) {
        DeleteRecursive(sourceLocation);
    }
}

static void DeleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
            DeleteRecursive(child);

    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

}

And the code for the paste button:

```
        case R.id.context_accept_paste:
        MoveFiles copy = new MoveFiles(new ProgressDialog(this), path);
        copy.execute(filesMoving);  
        for (int i = 0; i < filesMoving.size(); i++)
            currentFileList.add(path + "/" + filesMoving.get(i).getName());
        selectedPaths.clear();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
        return true;
```

I know this is OutOfBounds exception but can't figure out why it keeps occuring. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Print count in Log and check.

Comment: where is line number 30 MoveFiles.java ?

Comment: It looks like you delete the file at the end of the copy call. I'm not sure exactly how file references work, but you may be deleting as you traverse the array?

Comment: `01-22 17:36:24.080: D/count(11397): 4`
logging count returns 4 
`01-22 17:36:24.095: E/AndroidRuntime(11397): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0` although it seems otherwise.

`01-22 17:36:24.095: E/AndroidRuntime(11397):  at com.example.myapp.MoveFiles.doInBackground(MoveFiles.java:32)`

MoveFiles.java line 32: ` copyDirectory(files.get(i), destination);`

what's going onnnn

Comment: Please write which line is 30?

Comment: `copyDirectory(files.get(i), destination);` is line 32

Comment: Try to paste files.size() into loop instead of count

Comment: the size is 0 itself.. that means no data

Comment: the size isn't 0.. files.size() how ever many files are selected (see above) the app crashes when they are being copied